# Fast calculation of intersections

Tags: python, gis, intersection, shapefile, geopandas

I would like to calculate the intersected area between a shape file and a fishnet grid.

Therefore, I use this approach (in a Python 3.7 environment):

```
import geopandas as gpd

fnet = gpd.read_file("foo/bar/fnet.shp")
shapes = gpd.read_file("foo/bar/shapes.shp")

geom_fnet  = [x for x in fnet.geometry]
geom_shapes   = [x for x in shapes.geometry]

intersections = []
for i, geolist1 in enumerate(geom_fnet):
    for j, geolist2 in enumerate(geom_shapes):
        if geolist1.intersects(geolist2):
            intersections.append((i, (geolist1.intersection(geolist2).area/geolist1.area)))

# next steps of analysis
```

The fishnet has a large number of tiles and I would like to use an approach faster than a for loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could take a look at `geopandas.overlay` (https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/set_operations.html). This gives you a new DataFrame with all all intersections of both layers. And based on that you should be able to do the area calculation.

Comment: It indeed worked out. Thanks for the hint!